# Extract data from nested json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL database with a 'params' field containing Json encoded data.  An example of the field contents is:

```
{"subcustom":{"slaveusers":["Jon Doe"]}}
```

How can I extract the name "Jon Doe" using Php?

Comment: Decode your json and see it's structure.

Comment: that's not nested json. that's just json. it becomes an array of arrays, basically, once you decode it. nested json woud be `{"subcustom":"{\"slaveusers\":....}"}`. e.g. a json encoded string that contained ANOTHER separate json-encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) to transform your json string into an object, if you know what you are looking for, do

```
<?php
    $json = '{"subcustom":{"slaveusers":["Jon Doe"]}} ';
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print_r($obj->subcustom->slaveusers[0]) ; // Jon Doe
?>
```

if you don't know the structure of your json, use a `print_r` or `vardump` to check the content

Answer (score 0):

To do this as array you add the 'true' flag to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$json = '{"subcustom":{"slaveusers":["Jon Doe"]}} ';
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($json_array); // Array ([subcustom] => Array ([slaveusers] => Array ([0] => Jon Doe)))
```

Once you have an array you can follow the tree to get the element(s) you want:

```
echo $json_array['subcustom']['slaveusers'][0]; // Jon Doe
```